# Showing progress bar while window is loading with wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have window with a lot of items and tools, what I want to do, and ask about, is how can I show a progress bar while the window is loading with a WPF  main or child window?

Comment: What exactly is blocking you from doing exactly that?

Comment: a simple way is just try to calculate the loading time and create a new wpf window with a loading bar and in code behind manage a timer of nearby time to the loading time and display it then.

Comment: If you're looking for a really easy solution without coding (looks like to me), you can also choose an image and set it's build action to  splash screen. No answer from me though, as you asked for something else.

Comment: Sorry, but this is the first time I try to using progress bar, please can you give me an example, will be so thankful for you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this link:

http://bensprogrammingwork.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/progressbar-in-wpf.html

Might be helpful, I could try to explain more but I don't really know what's your struggle.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless attempting to do that with WPF because by the time the `Framework` has loaded your application and you are able to display a `Window` with a progress bar, the `MainWindow.xaml` page will have already loaded.

There is a way to display a static image *before* the application has fully loaded, but you cannot animate any part of it. You can find out how to do that in the [How to: Add a Splash Screen to a WPF Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

If you definitely want a loading animation upon start up, you will have to wait until the application has finished loading and then 'pretend' to the users that it is still loading with your animation... pretty pointless I think you would agree.

Even so, if you are determined to go down that path, you can find a working example of a loading animation in the [A Simple WPF Loading Animation](http://elegantcode.com/2009/08/21/a-simple-wpf-loading-animation/) page on the ElegantCode website.

---

UPDATE >>>

Oh sorry, I didn't realise that this was not just for the start up `Window`. No, you can only use the splash screen upon application start up. The problem that you will find when displaying an animation when a `Window` is loading is that (generally) the `Window` is loaded using the UI thread. As your animation will also be using the UI thread, you will find that it probably won't run smoothly because the UI thread is busy loading and initialising the `Window`. You can still try using the last link that I provided for this, but don't expect too much.

Comment: I tried Splash Screen now, but it's using for application start up, can I use it for when specific windows loaded? that's what I want Sheridan.

Comment: Sheridan, Thank you so much for your time, I'm confused now and I don't know what's the best way to do what I want to do, please can you give me your opinion

Comment: The last line in my answer sums up my opinion: *You can still try... but don't expect too much.* It might work a bit, but it *will* freeze when the `Window` is loading. You could just have a simple text animation done with a `DispatcherTimer` updating a `TextBlock` at regular intervals, but again, that would probably freeze too. Try it and see... you might get lucky.

Comment: Now, I'm tring to use Backgrounworker, but how can I load the window from another window? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried use loading animation, Telerik busyindecator and backgroundworker but all these make the window frozen. Is it possible that there is no solution !!!

Comment: @YoMo, that's what he told you already.  WPF initializes from top down, so you have to be really clever or really lucky.